# Using @font-face to include a font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to access fonts that I have in my project folder. This is my CSS:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: Chunk;
src: url('C:\Users\Ray\Dropbox\Work\Programming in .NET\School\PIN_Assignment\PIN_Assignment\Fonts\Chunkfice.otf');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use a relative URL like so:

```
src: url("Fonts/Chunkfice.otf");
```

assuming the Fonts is in a sub directory inside the directory where your css file is.

or an absolute URL like:

```
src: url("/Fonts/Chunkfice.otf");
```

assuming the Fonts folder is in the root folder of your domain.

You're using the absolute path from your Windows filesystem instead. You can't access the local filesystem like that.